# How to format (Bold) Row Labels

Tags: ssas, mdx

I use the below scope statement to bold Measure Values.  Is there a way to make the corresponding row labels bold as well?

```
Scope ([Reports].[Income Statement].Members);


// Bold Font for Report Items //

FONT_FLAGS(THIS) = IIF([Reports].[Income Statement].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Income Statement].&[Total Sales],1,0);

FORMAT_STRING(THIS) = IIF([Reports].[Income Statement].CurrentMember IS [Reports].[Income Statement].&[Variable Margin],"#,##0.00 %;-#,##0.00 %","#,##0.00;(#,##0.00)");
End Scope;
```

This is how it looks in excel.  Only measure value is in bold and I need Row Label "Total Sales" in bold font as well.

[image]

[Excel Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eOyL.png)

Comment: where is `FONT_FLAGS` used ?  Do you need to use it against the hierarchy `[Reports].[Income Statement]` as well as measures?

Comment: The Dimension [Reports] doesn't have any hierarchy and it is designed to be a flat report.  Yes I would like to have the FONT_FLAGS used for both row label and measures based on the condition

Comment: Why would you want to possible go through this rigmarole? Using a logic at the reporting client, it could be handled much simpler way.

Comment: you mean in Excel? Yes, they could handle it easily.  However, it would be more finished report if I could achieve this through SSAS.

Comment: excel/ssrs...anything. As long as it does the job. What do you mean "more finished report"?

Comment: I've created a "Reports" dimension with different Financial Statements like Income Statement.  When user selects this attribute it populates the statement in a specific format and order.  In the above example, "Total Sales" is not an account code but only a Report Total.  I've used scope statement to calculate this total correctly and made the font bold for measure value.  All I need is "Total Sales" Row label in bold font as well.